# Meteor observe changes added callback on server fires on all item

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  DATA.find().observeChanges({
    added: function(id, doc) {
       console.log(doc);
    }
  });
});
```

This code is being called on the server. Every time the meteor server starts, the `added` function fires for every single item in the database. Is there a way to have the `added` callback fire only when new items are added?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`added` will be called for every document in the result set when `observeChanges` is first run. The trick is to ignore the callback during this initialization period. I have an expanded example in my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502638/meteor-subscribe-and-display-users-count) question, but this code should work for you:

```
(function() {
  var initializing = true;
  DATA.find().observeChanges({
    added: function(id, doc) {
      if (!initializing) {
        console.log(doc);
      }
    }
  });
  initializing = false;
})();
```

Note that [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) is a client-only function. On the server I think it only ever executes once.

Comment: This is so simple and I couldn't figure it out for days. Thankyou! How stupid of me to not realize that Deps.autorun is client only. Now I have one more question...if you could shed some light. If I run this function on a very large collection and never call stop, now that Meteor uses oplog, would it tax my system badly.

Comment: @Bads You want the after and before hooks functionality? https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks

Comment: @PeppeL-G So you would say that using the after and before hooks is better than observe changes?

Lets' say my use case is every time a document is added into a collection, modify it, then add that into another collection. Also I just looked through the entire document. It looks exactly like observeChanges. What is the difference?

Comment: @Bads Just mentioned it as an alternative. I don't think that package works with cursors, so I don't think that solution will have the memory drawback you mention in your solution (if it exists).

Comment: @PeppeL-G. I see. Thanks. I will experiment with both the solution.

Comment: @Bads I'll ask the core devs who work on this, but my gut tells me this isn't the right approach - if for no other reason than your startup time may be prohibitive if `DATA` is indeed a large collection. I think collection-hooks is a good suggestion to try out. I have not used it, but the code doesn't seem to contain the text "observe". An alternative is to only do inserts to your collection via a method call. That way your server code can always do the additional updates for you.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Thanks, I think you are right. For now I will go with before after hooks. It's super easy.

edit: The reason I did not want to include this after insert function in meteor method is because the data is coming from multiple method, and it would be nice if I just have one place to fun this function.

Comment: @Bads can you post your solution? I have tried using before and after but before actually doesn't get called before in many cases...

Answer (score 10):

I struggled with this for a long time. For some reason, David's answer did not work for me - it was firing after the initializing variable was set to false.

This pattern from Avi was successful for me:

```
var usersLoaded = false;
Meteor.subscribe("profiles", function () {
    // at this point all new users sent down are legitimately new ones
    usersLoaded = true;
});

Meteor.users.find().observe({
    added: function(user) {
        if (usersLoaded) {
            console.log("New user created: ", user);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @chaintng `profiles` is probably how John named his publication where he publishes the `Meteor.users` collection

Answer (score 4):

Since it is initialization issue, you can do this.

```
var observerOfMessages = Messages.find({}).observe({
    added: function(doc){
        if(!observerOfMessages) return;
        console.log(doc)
    }
});
```

This is more elegant actually.

Comment: For those who only use `let` or `const`, make sure to initialize it first, like so: `let observerOfMessages; observerOfMessages = Messages.find({})...` otherwise you'll get an error saying `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'observerOfMessages' before initialization`

Answer (score 2):

Provide a selector for the query which does not match old items. If using mongo ObjectID as `_id` you could query for items that have `_id` greater than the latest item's:

```
const latest = DATA.findOne({}, {sort: {_id: -1}})
DATA.find({_id: {$gt: latest._id}}).observeChanges({
  added: function() { ... }
})
```

Or with `createdAt` timestamp:

```
const currentTime = new Date()
DATA.find({createdAt: {$gt: currentTime}}).observeChanges({
  added: function() { ... }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to solve this:

```js
Meteor.subscribe('messages', function() {
    var messages = Messages.find();
    var msgCount = messages.count();

    messages.observe({
        addedAt: function(doc, atIndex) {
            if(atIndex > (msgCount - 1)) console.log('added');
        }
    });
});
```

Should only fire for docs added after the existing amount is delivered. It's important that this goes in an `onReady` callback for `Meteor.subscribe` so that the `msgCount` changes as your subscription does... if for example, you're paginating your subscriptions.

[`cursor.observe()` documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe)