# Meteor observe changes called for each document at startup

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am observing changes on my notifications collection to trigger a sounds on the client when they get a notification. However when the user first loads the app they keep getting a sound for every document in the collection. Any way to avoid this and only have it for every newly added one?

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
var query = Notifications.find({userId: Meteor.userId(), read: false});
var handle = query.observe({
     added: function(post) {
        var mySound = new buzz.sound( "/notification", {
        formats: [ "mp3", "ogg" ]
        });

        mySound.play();
      }  
  });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor observe changes added callback on server fires on all item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355802/meteor-observe-changes-added-callback-on-server-fires-on-all-item)

Comment: See David's linked question. If it is not server-side but client-side, then you can wait for the `ready` callback for a subscription.

Comment: Yep setting an initializing variable works perfectly!