# Meteor observe changes added callback

Tags: meteor

@DavidWeldon I tried your code ([Meteor observe changes added callback on server fires on all item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355802/meteor-observe-changes-added-callback-on-server-fires-on-all-item)) and it's very good thank you !

However I would like to have your advise : I use it for desktop notifications : when i get one notification, there is one console log (ok), but when i get another notification (total : 2), there are two console log (I want only one console log because there is only a +1 notification)

Here is my code :

```
if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
Notification.requestPermission();

var query = Notifications.find({userId: Meteor.userId(), read: false});
(function() {
  var initializing = true;
  query.observeChanges({
    added: function(id, notification) {
      if (!initializing) {
        console.log(notification);
      }
    }
  });
  initializing = false;
})();
```

Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer, exploring this post in discover meteor : https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/

(in my question, I was working in Template.notifications.helpers)

Here's my new code :

```
Template.notifications.onCreated(function () {

  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
  Notification.requestPermission();

  var instance = this;
  instance.autorun(function () {
    var query = Notifications.find({userId: Meteor.userId(), read: false});
    query.observeChanges({
      added: function(id, notification) {
        var notification = new Notification('Notification', {
          icon: '',
          body: "You got a new notification !"
        });
      }
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another flag in there?

```
if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
Notification.requestPermission();

var query = Notifications.find({userId: Meteor.userId(), read: false});
(function() {
  var initializing = true;
  var firstNotif = true;
  query.observeChanges({
    added: function(id, notification) {
      if (!initializing && firstNotif) {
        firstNotif = false;
        console.log(notification);
      }
    }
  });
  initializing = false;
})();
```

Comment: With that solution there is no console log displayed

Comment: Yep, my bad, sorry, I fixed my answer.