# Meteor: observeChanges after the template is fully loaded

Tags: meteor

I am experimenting with meteor and I'm facing some code structuring issue.
**What I want:**
I use an observer to keep track of new document added on collection, but i want to be 'notified' only after the the template is fully rendered.

In my router.js file i have:

```
HospitalListController = RouteController.extend({
  action: function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('hospitals');
    this.render('listHospitals');
  }
});
```

My client listHospital.js file is

```
Template.listHospitals.onRendered(function(){
  var first = true;
  hospitalsCursor = Hospitals.find();
  var totals = hospitalsCursor.count();
  var loaded = 0;

  HospitalsHandle = hospitalsCursor.observeChanges({
    added : function(doc){
      if( loaded != totals ){
        loaded++;
      }else{
        console.log("added "+doc);    
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Is there a better way, maybe a 'meteor-way' to accomplish that?

Comment: ok, so you want to handle 'Added' after the initial documents from the Collection are sent to the client ?   Perhaps try using Iron Router's waitOn()  : https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-waiton-option , then I think the rest of your logic should work.

Comment: just tried, but added callback is getting fired during template loading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My actual working code:

```
Template.queueView.onRendered(function(){
  var initialLoaded = false;

  Queues.find().observeChanges({
    added : function(id, doc){
      if( initialLoaded ){
        console.log("added "+id);  
        highlight();
        beep();

      }   
    },
    removed : function(id, doc){
      console.log("removed "+id);
      highlight();
      beep();
    },
    changed : function(){
      console.log('modified!');
      highlight();
      beep();
    }
  });


  Meteor.subscribe('queues', function(){
    initialLoaded = true;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a flag to ignore observeChange callback during initialization (found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355802/meteor-observe-changes-added-callback-on-server-fires-on-all-item)).

```
Template.listHospitals.onRendered(function(){

  var initialized = false;

  hospitalsCursor = Hospitals.find();

  HospitalsHandle = hospitalsCursor.observeChanges({
    added : function(doc){
      if(initialized) {
        // your logic
      }
    }
  });

 initialized = true;

});
```

This should work.

Comment: Does not work because observeChanges is asynchronous.