# How to wait observer call after Mongo insert on Meteor Server

Tags: meteor, node-fibers

I figured, when I insert into Mongo, Meteor's Fiber magic waits/blocks until the db acknowledged the write, but not until the observers are called. Is there a way to wait for them?

I'm inserting data in server code, and I have a Caching layer that observes added events on the Collection and casts ObjectModel instances from them:

```js
class CachingService {
  attachObservers() {
    this.collection.observe({
      added: models => this.added(models)
    })
  }
}
```

```js
const id = Placements.insert({...})
console.log(`Inserted ${id} -`, CachingServices.Placements.getByID(id), Placements.getByID(id, false))
```

would print:

> Inserted ... - undefined, {...}

i.e. the CachingService didn't receive the insert yet, but the database did.

Comment: Do you execute the insert within a Meteor method or outside of it?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try injecting the `observe` property on the collection cursor not the instance (i.e `testCollection.find().observe` ).

```
Meteor.startup(() => {

  const testCollection = new Mongo.Collection("testCollection");

  testCollection.find().observe({
  added: function(document) {
    console.log("groups observe added value function");
    console.log(document);
  }
});

  testCollection.insert({ foo: 'bar' });
})
```

Other helpful questions: 
[Meteor collection observe changes rightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621280/meteor-collection-observe-changes-rightly)
[cursor.observe({added}) behavior in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218534/cursor-observeadded-behavior-in-meteor)

Comment: We're already observing the cursor. It's the only way meteor supports doing it.  
The other questions you linked deal with observation events for already existing models - but we already handle that.